# create new string by adding characters of smaller strings one after another

Tags: python, string, merge

You have strings
"aaaaa"
"bbbbb"
"ccccc"
"ddddd"

Now you want to generate the string:

"abcdabcdabcdabcdabcd"

How would be the fastest way to do it?

PS. This is a very simplified example. I really need to generate the new string from the existing smaller strings.

Comment: Could the strings have different lengths? If so, what should happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings are of equal length you can use zip:

```
result = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(*strings)))
```

Comment: Alternative: `''.join(''.join(s) for s in zip(*strings))`

Comment: @user975135 [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) are three of the most useful function in Python. You should definitely learn to use them. The syntax might be confusing at first, but it's not hard to understand, and it's much shorter and nicer looking than a separate for loop.

Comment: Using itertools, you can work with irregular string lengths as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use izip_longest from the [itertools library](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izp_longest), and the flatten recipe from the same library.

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain
def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)

result = ''.join(flatten(izip_longest("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccc", "dddd", fillvalue='')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "aaaaaaaaa"
string2 = "bbbbbbbbb"
string3 = "ccccccccc"
string4 = "ddddddddd"
new_string = ""
for i in range(0,len(string1)):
    new_string = new_string+string1[i]+string2[i]+string3[i]+string4[i]
print (new_string)
```

Results:

```
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
```